# loop over 2 maps and find replace occurrences of a key from one map in another map

Tags: java-8, hashmap

I have the following code that loops over two collections and does the following:

```
     mapa.forEach((key, value) -> {

     key = Arrays.stream(key.split(" "))
                  .map(s -> mapb.getOrDefault(s.trim(),   s.trim()))
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

     });
```

I have 2 maps:

mapa:   {"cat cat bat", "45"}
mapb:   {"cat" "c"}

the above code replaces occurrences of cat with c.

mapa:   {"c c bat", "45"}

I want to modify the above code to split mapa key into two strings

"c c", "bat"

and use the 2 parts of the key and the corresponding value in as an argument to the method

method1("c c", "bat", "45");

How do I do this?

I am thinking using predicate with filter is one way but I need help with this.

Comment: How did you end up with this design?  Why does the key `c c bat` become two keys `c c` and `bat` ?

Comment: I want to split the key into two strings to do some processing. I even considered using  Triple<A,B,C>{

String parta = "c c";

String partb = "bat";

String partc = "45";

}

Comment: I need to have 3 parts now - the key is divided into 2 parts and the value is one part.

Comment: I would welcome if you have some design suggestions too

Comment: Explain the logic by which the string `c c bat` gets split into `c c` and `bat`.

Comment: Right now, "c c bat" is not split but I want it to to be split into "c c" and "bat". if you want to know why, because I need a lot of processing to do with "c c". I had to convert "c c" into some numerical value after doing a lot of processing.

Comment: Unfortunately, you seem unable to explain your logic.  Therefore, I can't offer any help.

Comment: Tim, which logic you need? There is no logic by which c c bat gets split into c c and bat. There is some info in the question that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

llakk, I don't get the purpose of this map looping but just for the sake of answering this question, I'm able to achieve what you've described with the following code.

```
public void mapKeyConversion() {

    Map<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> mapb = new HashMap<>();
    mapa.put("cat cat bat", "45");
    mapb.put("cat", "c");

    mapa.entrySet().stream().
            map(entry -> Arrays.stream((entry.getKey().concat(" " + entry.getValue())).split(" ")).
            map(s -> mapb.getOrDefault(s.trim(), s.trim())).
            collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
            ).forEach(s -> {
                String[] sarr = s.split(" ");
                method1(sarr[0] + " " + sarr[1], sarr[2], sarr[3]);
            });
}

public void method1(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
    System.out.println(arg1 + " " + arg2 + " " + arg3);
}
```

The output is:

```
c c bat 45
```

**NOTE**: `c c` is a single string. It can be inferred from the number of arguments of the method `method1()`.

Comment: Thank you mark42inbound. This solution is helpful to me. I couldn't explain the purpose of this looping because this is a very small part of the big project and I am experimenting with different ways here. Thank you again. I appreciate it.